# Clojure Web App libraries selection

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Going to start a new Web app in Clojure, going to use the following libraries as a base to start with but would like to hear of others instead or in addition:

Om - UI

Secretary - Client side navigation **(replace with Bidi or Silk?)**

Sente - Client/Server communication

Ring/Compojure/HttpKit - Web server

Component - Application architecture/modularity/reloaded pattern **(Something else here?)**

Friend - Authentication/Authorization **(Buddy instead?)**

Liberator - REST web services **(Any alternative?)**

Figwheel, Weasel, Reloaded Pattern - Development sugar

Comment: This would be a better question for programmers.SE.

Comment: Is there an option here somewhere to move questions to another SE?

Comment: There is worth to consider alternative of Om - [Reagent](http://holmsand.github.io/reagent/).

Comment: I know that people with sufficient points or other power can move questions.  I'm not sure how it's done though.  You could just copy your text and ask a new question.  You could then delete the original question, but I don't recommend doing that now, since you've got an answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This answer really depends on what you actually need. There's no such thing as an overall combination of libraries that you should always use as a starting point for a project. You haven't specified your requirements, so we can't say what you should put into your project.

Here are some general observations:

Many Om apps are single-page apps, loaded from a single URL. If that's your case as well, you don't need Secretary. If you have multiple URLs all using the same compiled clojurescript file, then that's where Secretary comes into the picture. But if you are not using :advanced optimizations with clojurescript, then you also don't need Secretary since you can explicitly load a particular namespace on each page. Depends on the level of complexity and deployment you are desiring.

You mention Http Kit, do you have specific needs for that over Jetty, which tends to be much more common? If it is because you want websockets, it is worth considering why you need websockets. They are cool but should be given consideration before adopting them as your default environment, in my opinion. Websockets are certainly not without their flaws, and most cases of server-browser communication are handled very easily, simply and in a more stable manner by using normal request/response and ajax, which has been around much longer and is something worth knowing and using, even if you later decide websockets are worthy of exploration. I would recommend `cljs-ajax` library for that purpose.

You should add the `fogus EDN library` to your list, since it is Ring middleware that will handle data transfer between browser and client regardless of your preferred transport method.

Your choice for an authorization library really depends on the type of authorization you need. There isn't a one-size-fits-all in that area.

Comment: Indeed we are talking about a single page application, loaded from a single URL. Will use :advanced optimizations for production.

Routing/navigation in single page applications still makes sense as a mean to navigate between logical screens in the application - also navigation history/back button, urls into a specific screen, etc..

Comment: I've used Http Kit successfully in other projects and in addition to websockets and streaming it has better performance than jetty.
I believe that the application will benefit from websockets support with a fallback and this is exactly what the above mentioned Sente library provides.

Authentication will be a login screen with a user/password which is validated against a database users table. Also roles and permissions so I'd like to manage access to the different web services using these.

Comment: Ok, just make sure that if you need a secure websocket, I don't think http-kit offers that, though perhaps you aren't handling sensitive data to your server.